# I get a nullPointerException when I'm trying to add some values to a referenced class from another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am c# programmer and I am used to c#'s syntaxes for encapsulation and other stuff.But now,due to some reasons,I should write something with java and I am practicing java for a day now!I am going to create a dummy project for my self in order to make myself more comfortable with java's oop concepts

What I am trying to do is that I want a class named 'Employee' which has three properties(fields):`firstName`,`lastName`,and `id`.And then I want to create another class named `EmployeeArray` which will construct an array of `Employee`s within itself and can perform some operations on it(for some reasons I want this project this way!!)
Now I want to add some values to the `Employee`s within the `EmployeeArray` class.here's my work so far:

```
//this is the class for Employee
public class Employee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int id;
public void SetValues(String firstName, String lastName, int id) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
}

//this is the EmployeeArray class
public class EmployeeArray {
private int numOfItems;
private Employee[] employee;

public EmployeeArray(int maxNumOfEmployees) {
    employee = new Employee[maxNumOfEmployees];
    numOfItems = 0;
}

public void InsertNewEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, int id){
    try {
        employee[numOfItems].SetValues(firstName, lastName, id);
        numOfItems++;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

//and this is the app's main method
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
EmployeeArray employeeArray;
employeeArray = new EmployeeArray(input.nextInt());

String firstName;
String lastName;
int id;

firstName = input.nextLine();
lastName = input.nextLine();
id = input.nextInt();

employeeArray.InsertNewEmployee(firstName, lastName, id);
```

the problem is I get a nullPointerException when the app wants to set the values,and it is happening in the `employeeArray` reference.I don't know what I am missing.Any suggestions?

Comment: Paste the stack trace for the error please.

Change this line: `System.out.println(e.toString());` to `e.printStackTrace();` and you can debug the cause yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I am c# programmer and I am used to c#'s syntaxes for encapsulation
>   and other stuff."

Good. Then you should feel pretty much at home with Java :).

> "The problem is I get a nullPointerException when the app wants to set
>   the values".

In C#, if you have an array of objects, then you must first allocate the array ... and then you *ALSO* need to "new" any object you PUT in the array.  Don't you?

Same in Java :)

Suggested change:

1) Lose your "SetNewValues()" function.

2) Make sure "Employee" has a constructor that accepts first name, last name, and id.

3) Change your "insert" method:

```
public void InsertNewEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, int id){
    try {
        employee[numOfItems] = new Employee(firstName, lastName, id);
        numOfItems++;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes!Now I saw it!!I don't know why I was trying to create a reference of `Employee` in the `EmployeeArray`'s constructor!!!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you didn't make a employee object

do this:

```
public void InsertNewEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, int id){
try {
    employee[numOfItems]=new Employee();
    employee[numOfItems].SetValues(firstName, lastName, id);
    numOfItems++;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```